# How do I make multiple 2D lights in OpenGL look good

Tags: java, opengl, 2d, lwjgl

I am making a 2D top-down game using LWJGL. I have implemented multiple point lights using shaders but they don´t look good. Or they do look good until the lights meet. I will put screenshots and the code below:

[image: Screenshot]

Vertex shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec2 position;
in vec2 texCoords;

out vec2 passTexCoords;
out float lightDistance;

uniform mat4 uProjection;
uniform mat4 uView;
uniform vec2 lightPosition;
uniform float aspect;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = uProjection * uView * vec4(position, 1.0, 1.0);
    passTexCoords = texCoords;

    vec4 cameraLightPos = uProjection * uView * vec4(lightPosition, 1.0, 1.0);
    vec2 finalLightPos = vec2(cameraLightPos.x * aspect, cameraLightPos.y);
    vec2 finalPos = vec2(gl_Position.x * aspect, gl_Position.y);
    lightDistance = distance(finalLightPos, finalPos);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec2 passTexCoords;
in float lightDistance;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;
uniform vec3 lightColor;
uniform float lightIntensity;
uniform bool affectedByAmbient;
uniform vec3 ambientColor;
uniform vec3 fontColor;

void main(void) {
    vec4 tex_color = texture(textureSampler, passTexCoords);
    if (tex_color.a < 1.0)
        discard;

    float diffuse = 0.0;

    if (lightDistance <= lightIntensity)
        diffuse = 1.0 - abs(lightDistance / lightIntensity);

    if (affectedByAmbient)
        gl_FragColor = vec4(
                min(tex_color.rgb * ((lightColor * diffuse) + ambientColor),
                        tex_color.rgb), 1.0);
    else
        gl_FragColor = vec4(
                min(
                        (tex_color.rgb * fontColor)
                                * ((lightColor * diffuse) + vec3(1, 1, 1)),
                        tex_color.rgb), 1.0);
}
```

As you can see when 2 or more lights meet it doesn't look good. I have no idea on how to fix this so I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: We'd need to see the CPU code that drives this, but I think what is going on is that you pass only one light at a time to the vertex and fragment shaders.  So where the lights meet, there should be overlapping light sources (more than one light) and instead you get a hard and kind of arbitrary boundary where ever the last tile got drawn.

Comment: To add to markspace: what you'll want to do, is to have multiple lights in the shaders (e.g. an array of lights) and loop over them, adding their diffuse contributions. If the object uses ambient light, then only add it once.

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right. I feel kinda dumb for not realizing that on my own. I will try it out and post the result.

Comment: What's the lightPosition? Only one light is being accounted for in each pixel, which is the one whose lightPosition you used

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I only sent one light to the shader. Fixed it easily buy sending in an array of lights.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).